# Pass list item metadata to filter for document library

Tags: web-part, filter

looking for a way to filter a document library based on metadata from an item in a different library.

For example I would have two web parts on a page , selecting on in item in library one would filter library 2 based on the value of a column from the item that was selected in list one.

Can this be acomplished with something ootb? or using the client object model or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

This normally can be accomplished by using connectable webparts. Make sure to tick "allow Connections" under the advanced webpart settings.

Whenever you select the dropdown menu of a webpart, you can choose "connections", and select the webpart that you want to connect to. You then can configure your connection to filter the data based on a specific selection.

Comment: I never got this working with metadata columns. I suppose it is not supported for this column type?

Comment: do you mean managed metadata or enterprise keyword columns?

Comment: managed metadata columns.