# Filter by metadata through connection to another item

Tags: managed-metadata, filter, connected-web-parts, term-store, metadata

I was wondering if it is possible to filter a list item based on metadata values from another list item.

I tested it locally but it didn't seem to work althougth another post here said it should work ([Pass list item metadata to filter for document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16015/pass-list-item-metadata-to-filter-for-document-library)). Created a list with a Term Store field and then created another list using the same term store field. Populated both lists with items and made sure that all lists have items that should match. Then I set up the connection on the one list and created the filter so that the Term Store field from list A should filter the Term Store from list B. But unfortunately this results in no results at all althought it should have any results (if the filter were actually working).

Is this a known issue with SharePoint 2010? It just seems weird that they offer those fields for selection on the filter dialogue when they seem to be not supported.

Comment: Interesting, it should work as described but I've never tried specifically with metadata columns. Did you try with another (simpler) type to make sure you have the correct recipe?

Comment: Also when two lists are connected, it should give you a new column in the master list indicating which is selected for filter. You have to select one to get some values in the 2nd list, unless you configure the webpart's option to not send a row by default.

Comment: Yes, it works with "normal" columns, like single line of text or choice. The lists are (and don't have to be) connected - no lookup exists from list A to B. This isn't needed an isn't a problem when using other column types as I don't want to filter based on the connection lookup but on custom defined column values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems this is a limitation of the managed metadata columns in SharePoint 2010. Let's hope a future SharePoint version will improve this behaviour.